# Install customized version of configuration file in Inno Setup after (Firebird) subinstaller finishes

Tags: inno-setup, firebird

I'm trying to install Firebird 3 along with my application using Inno Setup and I need to distribute a customized version of `firebird.conf` file to replace the default that comes with Firebird. How to do that? Any options of the following would be enough:

1. Copy `Firebird.conf` after Firebird is installed. (I'm not able to do that since the file added in `[Files]` section is always copied before running Firebird installation).
2. Download sources for Firebird, add my `firebird.conf` there and create a new Firebird installer. (No idea where to get all the necessary files for this)

Comment: You can get the necessary files from https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/ with instructions on https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/building-the-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to install a file after installation completes is by extracting it programmatically from [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "Firebird.conf"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('Installing Firebird.conf');
    ExtractTemporaryFile('Firebird.conf');
    if not FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Firebird.conf'),
                    ExpandConstant('{app}\Firebird.conf'), False) then
    begin
      RaiseException('Could not install Firebird.conf');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

For alternatives, see [Overwrite installed files with files in setup subfolder in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65161551/850848).